# Short story where a man wakes up in mist and is attacked by a "cyborg"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Read a short story in Warren's *Creepy* or *Eerie* in the mid 1970's. Can't remember name, artist, writer or issue.

Synopsis: A ragged man wakes up in mist, not knowing where he is or how he got there. He hears, then sees, a human torso/tracked chassis robot approach. After a brief conversation, they battle. The man lies down, fatally wounded. The robot produces a med-kit. The final panel has the man, alone and waking, not knowing where he is or how he got there.

Comment: Was this a comic or illustrated novel rather than just "plain words"?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Creepy and Eerie (IIRC) were black and white comic magazines. [Warren publishing at archive.org](https://archive.org/details/warrenpublishing)